# Using *args and a default parameter in python

Tags: python, variadic-functions, default-parameters

I have a function that utilizes both a default parameter and *args:

```
def greeting(name, *args, exclamation='yo!'):
    for arg in args:
        print(name, arg, exclamation)
```

This seems to work fine. However, when I check it with flake8, it returns:

```
1 col 38| E901 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am stickler for both following correct practice and having my checks clear. Am I doing this wrong? Is a different method standard?

Comment: In Python 3, this is legal but `exclamation` would be a keyword-only argument, meaning it'd **have** to passed like `greeting('Joe', some, args, exclamation='!')`. Useful, but not necessarily what you want.

Comment: @delnan No, you wouldn't *have* to specify it if it has a default value(like in OP's example).

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, my wording was ambiguous. It wouldn't have to be passed, but if it was passed it would have to be passed in this manner rather than positionally.

Comment: I probably missed the `like` just before the code :s

Comment: This is just a long shot, but is flake8 calibrated for Python 3.x?  Your code runs fine in Python 3.x but crashes in 2.x, leading me to believe that your version of flake8 is for 2.x.

Comment: @iCodez, I'm not sure, but that certainly could be it. Do you happen to know how to change this?

Comment: @delnan, that is what I'm going for. I'm just trying to clear the error.

Comment: @iCodez, that was exactly it! `sudo pip-3.2 install flake8` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As iCodez guessed, this was the result of unintentionally using a version of flake8 designed for Python 2.x. Installing the Python 3 version with `sudo pip-3.2 install flake8` solved the problem.